# Django - Internationalization won't work

Tags: django, internationalization

I have the following line of code which basically returns an error - a translated error -  along with a view in a case of a failure:

```
from django.utils.translation import ugettext_lazy as _
.....

return render_to_response('login.html',{'form': form,'error_message':_("User is not in the group %s" % group_name),'settings':SettingsManager.get()},context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

And I created the message files, and compiled them. But the thing is it is only displayed as I wrote it - in English, `User is not in the group %s" % group_name`. Part of my django.po file:

```
#: application/views.py:1003
#, python-format
msgid "User is not in the group %s"
msgstr "Kullanıcı %s grubunda değil."
```

ANy ideas how to solve it? I cannot see the problem.

P.S: **All the other translations are working like a charm, but this one is not.**

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

```
_("User is not in the group %s") % group_name
```

instead of

```
_("User is not in the group %s" % group_name)
```

that way the translation machinery has a constant string to look up.